# Is it a good practice to always combine a View with a ViewModel?

Tags: android, android-viewmodel

Many user defined View classes, maybe most of them, display any form of data. Is it a good habit to always combine a View with a ViewModel?

Comment: The "view" in view-model is not tied to `View` as an Android class. I would expect a view-model to be implemented at a higher level than a `View`, and something that is lifecycle-aware, such as an activity or fragment.

Comment: @CommonsWare  So you would end up in one ViewModel per activity or fragment?

I try to keep Android out of my actual model, as I may want to reuse it on a website. So I consider to use the ViewModel as a kind of adapters, that mainly subscribe and unsubscribe the observers.

Comment: "So you would end up in one ViewModel per activity or fragment?" -- if you are using the Architecture Components, yes, though more complex scenarios are possible (e.g., composite view-models).

Comment: Yes, when it comes to iteration over components, matching to activity does not work well. As soon as you use a fragment per iterated component your architecture becomes working again, I think.